# rails 3, how to do this easy query across two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I think this is a trivial query but it eludes me...

```
person has_many items
item has_many keywords
```

Item has fields id, person_id, name

Keyword has fields id, item_id, txt

In my Person controller:

```
def find_all_items_matching_keyword(aword)
   ????
end
```

is there a single query that returns all the items where (item.person_id = self.id) and the associated (keyword.txt = aword)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This query is simple enough that you should build it up with a single scope like this:

```
class Item
  scope :by_keyword, lambda{ |keyword| joins(:keywords).where('keywords.txt = ?', keyword) }
end
```

You can then query all items, in your controller, for a particular person like this:

```
class PersonsController
  def action
    @person = Person.find(params[:id])
    @items_by_keyword = @person.items.by_keyword(params[:aword])
  end
end
```

You can then loop over that list in your view, for example:

```
<% @items.by_keyword.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: that's very cool, thank you! learned two new things from that one answer!

Answer (score 2):

You code should look something like

```
def find_all_items_matching_keyword(aword)
   return Item.joins(:keyword).where("keywords.txt=':keyword'",{:keyword => aword })
end
```

and it should go in helpers (thats its correct place).

Answer (score 1):

you can use find_by_sql http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#finding-by-sql

if you want to be database agnostic, you should be able to do

```
items.keywords.each do |keyword| {
   #do stuff
}
```

activerecord should lazy load associated models for you.

Comment: Thanks, but we're querying a large table of keywords and finding the matching items, so iterating with .each wouldn't be a good idea. the finding-by-sql was helpful, but I'm hoping there is a activerecord query that would be database agnostic. I need to specify a simple inner join I think.